# Skip the extra popup confirmation window "Nominate this question for reopening?" to streamline the "Reopen votes" review process

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen, user-experience

I was going through questions in the review queue [Reopen votes: Vote whether or not to reopen closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen). I clicked on <kbd>Reopen</kbd>.

[image]

I expected this to reopen the question. Instead, I got a popup window <kbd>Nominate this question for reopening?</kbd>, which results in an extra click to confirm that I want to reopen the question.

[image]

Note that <kbd>Skip</kbd> does not result in the extra popup window asking me to confirm.

**I suggest to skip the extra popup confirmation window <kbd>Nominate this question for reopening?</kbd> to streamline the review process.**

Comment: That's not related to design, but rather to the user experience of the review process.